# Slow Network Connection

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04, the problem is that my connection (wifi) with only one network is very slow and is constantly disconnecting. I have already tried to connect with other networks and everything is fine. And the other people connected on that network, have no problems.

I have already tried chage `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4` to `hosts: files dns` and didn't work

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e04b]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] [10de:1341] (rev a2)

Comment: You need to give more information.  Your last sentence is unfinished, what is it that you have tried?

Comment: I tried chage "hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4" to "hosts: files dns" and didn't work

Comment: Please edit the question with those notes.

Comment: Sorry for bad copreension, but what notes?

Comment: Add the text you put on your second comment to the actual post so the post itself is self-contained.  People should should have to read the post and the comments to understand what you are asking and what you have tried.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Is the network that you have trouble with your home network and do you have the ability and permission to change settings in the router?

Comment: No, and I have not the ability and permission to change router settings